# How to find the newest date with reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have `items` object as below. And I would like to find the object whose `created` is the newest.

```
const items = [
        { id: 'djw8701', created: '2019-10-05T11:06:20.208Z', url: 'url1' },
        { id: 'djw8702', created: '2019-10-15T12:06:21.208Z', url: 'url2' },
        { id: 'djw8703', created: '2019-10-20T13:06:22.208Z', url: 'url3' }
      ]
```

I would like to compare the objects in the array and get one with newest date `items[2]`

My approach below returns nothing.

```
items?.reduce((curr, acc) => {
          if (curr.created < acc.created) {
            return { ...acc };
          }
        })
```

Comment: The reduce returns undefined when the it is falsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert it to `new Date()` so you can compare them.

```js
const deliveries = [{ id: 'HgP6cJB03', deliveryDate: '2022-10-20T13:06:22.208Z', url: 'some link3' }, { id: 'HgP6cJB01', deliveryDate: '2022-10-05T11:06:20.208Z', url: 'some link1' }, { id: 'HgP6cJB02', deliveryDate: '2022-10-15T12:06:21.208Z', url: 'some link2' }, ]

//When curr is newest we retun {...curr} if it's not we just return current accumulator {...acc}
const newest = deliveries.reduce((acc, curr) => new Date(curr.deliveryDate) > new Date(acc.deliveryDate) ? {...curr} : {...acc});
console.log(newest);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do the comparison, do something similar to

```
if (new Date(curr.deliveryDate) < new Date(acc.deliveryDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the delivery dates are always formatted as ISO-8601 then you can do it as simple as this:

```js
const deliveries = [
  { id: 'HgP6cJB01', deliveryDate: '2022-10-05T11:06:20.208Z', url: 'some link1' },
  { id: 'HgP6cJB02', deliveryDate: '2022-10-15T12:06:21.208Z', url: 'some link2' },
  { id: 'HgP6cJB03', deliveryDate: '2022-10-20T13:06:22.208Z', url: 'some link3' }
];

const oldest = deliveries.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc.deliveryDate < curr.deliveryDate ? curr : acc
);

console.log(oldest);
```

It returns a reference to an item of `deliveries` so be cautious about modifying it. If you need a copy then you can simply destructure the value returned by `Array.reduce()` and re-compose it into a new object:

```js
const oldest = { ... deliveries.reduce() }
```

There is no need to create copies on each iteration of `Array.reduce()`; the callback does not modify the objects that it works with.